# Angular 11 passing HttpParams different from String type

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm using Angular 11 and I'm trying to pass parameters to backend with right type (the type I need on the backend side) to my `@GetMapping` controller.

If I try to do:

```
getData(page: Number, firstId: Number, secondId: Number): Observable<AirpollData[]> {
  let params = new HttpParams();
  params = params.append('page', page);           // #1
  params = params.append('firstId', firstId);     // #2
  params = params.append('secondId', secondId);   // #3
  return this.http.get<MyObject[]>('data', { params: params });
}
```

I obtain for all 3 line (#1 ,2 and 3) the following error:

```
Argument of type 'Number' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'
```

Instead if I try to pass parameter as `@PathVariable` instead of as `@RequestParam` as following:

```
getaData(firstId: Number, secondId: Number, page: Number): Observable<MyObject[]> {
 return this.http.get<AirpollData[]>('data/' + firstId+ '/' + secondId+ '/' + page);
}
```

It does half of the work.. if the parameter are set everything goes fine but if they are set to null:

```
this.service.getData(null, null, this.page).subscribe(success => {
  .....
});
```

I obtain an error on backend side:

```
Number format exception for String value "null"
```

Is there a way to do something like that?
Or I must cast all parameters I'm passing from `String` to something else?

--------------------- UPDATE ----------------------

I want to use the same method for various call but I'm pretty new to Angular.. On my backend I would like to do something like that:

```
@Repository
public interface MyRepository extends JpaRepository<MyObject, Integer>, JpaSpecificationExecutor<MyObject> {

}
```

And:

```
public class MyObjectSpecification {

public static Specification<MyObject> findByCountry(Integer countryId) {
    if (countryId == null)
        return (root, query, cb) -> cb.conjunction();
    else return (root, query, cb) -> cb.equal(root.get("id"), countryId);
}

public static Specification<MyObject> findByCity(Integer cityId) {
    if (cityId == null)
        return (root, query, cb) -> cb.conjunction();
    else return (root, query, cb) -> cb.equal(root.join("cities").get("id"), cityId);
}
}
```

And:

```
public List<ObjectDto> getData(Integer countryId, Integer cityId, Integer page) throws ItemNotFoundException {
    Specification<Country> spec = Specification.where(CountrySpecification.findByCountry(countryId)
                                        .and(CountrySpecification.findByCity(cityId)));
    
    Page<MyObject> entities = repository.findAll(spec, PageRequest.of(0, page)); // page obviously is never null
    if (entities.isEmpty()) throw new ItemNotFoundException("Entities not found!");
    return mapper.toDtoS(entities.toList());
}
```

But I can't because I don't reach the following controller:

```
@GetMapping("/data/{countryId}/{cityId}/{page}")
public List<ObjectDto> getData(@PathVariable("countryId") Integer countryId, 
                                @PathVariable("cityId") Integer cityId, 
                                @PathVariable("page") Integer page) throws Exception {
 ....
 ....
```

Yes I can write more method, or using 20 if else.. passing 50 String and cast one by one.. but I prefer not.. Then the question remain the same..

Comment: Why not just use e.g. `.append("page", \`${page}\`)` in your first attempt, to make the values into strings? And what _do_ you expect to happen if there are nulls for any of the values?

Answer (score 0):

it seems that instead of going forward they're going backwards.. with Angular 11 the new `HttpClient` doesn't Support `Number`, `Boolean` and `Date` but only `String`.

[Here](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/23856) is the bug report.

The simple solution is:

```
call(param1: Number, param2: Number, param3: Number): Observable<AirpollData[]> {
 let params = new HttpParams();
 params = params.append('param1', '');               // pass as null
 params = params.append('param2', '');               // pass as null
 params = params.append('param3', page.toString());  // pass as Number (Integer)
 return this.http.get<Object[]>('data', { params: params });
}
```